# Windows 10 keeps adding another keyboard layout

Tags: windows-10, input-languages

I'm using Windows 10 in english with a pt-br keyboard, but sometimes it randomly adds an US keyboard in my tray area input list.
The input doesn't show in my configurations -> input list, as show in the image below:
[image]

This just annoys a bit when I cycle through the languages, but doesn't seem to affect anything else.
And it appears to be random, sometimes I log in and there's no US keyboard, only my PTB2 one. What could be causing this?

Comment: Having the same issue using a custom T2 based keyboard layout. Sometimes it just reverts adds the default German one for me. Rather annoying. I think it might be triggered by some programs, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, my Win10 keeps adding Italian layout, but it "doesnàt" show in the option, to remove it I need to add it manually first and then remove it. Incredibly annoying, cannot find a solution for months now...

Comment: I found this thread: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-2935897/prevent-windows-creating-keyboard-layout-based-regional-settings.html in the very end there is a solution which seems to have worked for someone: delete everything in the system related to the keyboard layout that is bothering you. I haven't tried it yet, but I may.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following instructions.

1. **Control Panel > Language**
2. If 'English (United States)' is not a visible option then re-add it by clicking 'Add a language'
3. Once added click 'options' on the US language and add an input language.
4. Add the pt-br input method.
5. Remove the United States input method.
6. Go back to 'Change your language preferences' and remove the English (United States) language you had added.

Hope this helps! good luck. (:

Comment: The language doesn't show in my control panel, but I tried adding it and removing it. After 7~ or so restarts, the US language is back again mysteriously.

Comment: I might suggest for Reset option with keeping your files. So, windows files will be re-installed and scan immediately with Antivirus for possible mystery. Normally, the above-mentioned steps should fix.